# Is there any way to get the remaining time of animation?

Tags: jquery, animation

Suppose I have some div, and I use `.animate({opacity:0},400, function(){});` for its children.
Is it ever possible then to get the remaining time for an animation to complete? eg, 200 ms remaining, or 0 if there's no animation?
Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity... why you need that value?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan. It's a hobby I guess. He's collection animations times.

Comment: I have problem with queuing some callbacks to the children - it doesn't always trigger, and it isn't easy to determine which child queue it to, so I wanted to try with setTimeout to make it more reliable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To help you better understand how you can use the `step` function
[as posted by *gdoron*]
 I created an example using the *step*  function to get the remaining time:

(click the `get state!` button to stop the animation and retrieve the remaining time!)

**[demo with distance](http://jsbin.com/akebaz/2/edit)**
**[demo with opacity](http://jsbin.com/akebaz/3/edit)**

Distance example jQuery:

```
var time = 4000;
var distance = 300;
var currentTime = 0;

$('#ball').animate({
    left: distance
}, {
    duration: time,
    step: function (now, fx) {

        currentTime = Math.round((now * time) / distance);
        var data = fx.prop + ' ' + Math.round(now) + '; <b>' + currentTime + 'ms</b> ';

        $('body').append('<p>' + data + '</p>');
    },
    easing: 'linear'
});

$('#getTime').click(function () {
    $('#ball').stop();
    $('body').prepend('<p>currentTime is:' + currentTime + ' ms; REMAINING: ' + (time - currentTime) + 'ms</p>');
});
```

- You can see how I used the `fx.prop` inside the `animation step` to get the (`left`) property that is currently animated.
- You can see how: knowing the animation time and the distance (opacity, whatever...) we can easily retrieve the 'stopped/paused' state by some simple math (`(now*time)/distance`) and thanks to the returned `now` value.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful! And seems it wont hit much the performance if we limit the step function to just variable writing. Anyway it ain't gonna be called every 1 ms or something.

Comment: @user1125062 It should not, cause we are only accessing something that is already running our animation.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea why do you need it, but the `step` can help you extract this value:

**Step Function**

> The second version of .animate() provides a step option — a callback function that is fired at each step of the animation. This function is useful for enabling custom animation types or altering the animation as it is occurring. It accepts two arguments (now and fx), and this is set to the DOM element being animated.
>
> **now**: the numeric value of the property being animated at each step
> **fx**: a reference to the jQuery.fx prototype object, which contains a number of properties such as elem for the animated element, start and end for the first and last value of the animated property, respectively, and prop for the property being animated.

[**docs**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: hmmm, but what do I supposed to do with that?  :)

Comment: @user1125062. You can get the the current value, the first value, the last value etc', just play with it. Anyway I'm sure there're other ways of doing what you're trying to do...

Comment: Without a setInterval or this method, no, AFAIK. These are the only ways to get it.

Answer (score 3):

Listen, never mind the `step` function everybody keeps talking about. I once needed what you do and wrote my own that simply put it reverse engineered the time left by having a look at total animation time (should already be known to you since you once gave this number to jQuery) and the *quotient* of the current and target opacity. Then just multiply that quotient with the total animation time, have the sum subtracted from the total time. Simple as that.

**Pseudo-code:**

```
func calculate-time-left-in-a-running-fade-in-animation:
{
    var current_opacity = $elem.css('opacity');
    var target_opacity = this.getTargetOpacity();

    var total = this.getTotalAnimationTime();

    var quotient = current_opacity / target_opacity;
    return total - quotient * total;
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, haven't though of it! Though if precision was important, step is the only way to go.

Comment: Retrieving the attribute value yourself or using the now variable is the very same thing, as long as the animation is paused. In the jQuery step-example @roXon gave there will be a lot of overhead going on, at every step of the animation. Might even introduce global variables like the example actually did. If you intend to pause the animation before computation (again like the example did) and programmatically resume the animation afterwards, then there's absolutely no difference at all. I'd even say that getting this computed value under a running animation would produce the same results.

Comment: The stored product of the step logic, the computed value of remaining time, isn't like a live list, the value doesn't update itself to the utmost accurate value. And it won't be anything but an "old" computation you use whenever wherever you use it. You will even have a middle man responsible for bridging this information gap, the step function, who should in theory thwart precision. But if you instead make the very same computation _exactly when you need to know_ remaining time, wouldn't that even be more accurate? And cheaper too, both in readability of code and processing overhead.

Comment: I think you are right! I'm going to take this weapon into my armory. Thanks for great answer. :)