# JQuery: how to make a superposition of many moving animations which start asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I want to make one animation superimposed on another. **The second (the third, the fourth) animation can start asynchronously**. To do that I need to specify difference between new and old positions (not absolute 'left').

E.g.

```
// One moment
$( '#my_div' ).animate( { 'leftShift': "+20px", 2000, 'easeOutQuad' } );

// Another moment, may be a second later
$( '#my_div' ).animate( { 'leftShift': "+50px" }, 2000, 'easeOutQuad' );
```

**Is it possible to add results of several animations?**

The graph to clarify what I want (X-axis: time, Y-axis: speed of distance change).

[image]

I'd like to see that speeds of animations are added, not the one-by-one animations.

What did Roko C. Buljan offer?

[image]

But I don't want *deferred* animations, I want a *real-time* animation.

Note. The current syntax ("+20px", "+50px") is not supported now. It's just for the example.

Comment: not, but `"+=20px", "+=50px"` is

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Does it work for the 'asynchronous' case?

Comment: Sure if you use `.stop()`, it will superimpose the new animation over the current one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem for my case.

I need very smooth animation. So, when a user initiates a new push, it should be like a new impulse. So, an object mustn't be stopped before.

I choose an 'easing' function for smooth movement - '[easeInOutQuad](http://easings.net/en)'. I implemented my own version (I removed not necessary parameters which was for standart 'easing' options of jQuery):

```
// Some browsers works bad if there is float px

function asyncAnimate( obj, props, duration, easing )
{
    function _getTime()
    {
        var d = new Date();
        return d.getTime();
    }       

    var startTime = _getTime();
    var duration = duration;

    var animNum = asyncAnimate._animNum;

    var propInts = {}; // to increment only ints
    var propFloats = {};

    for( var iProp in props )
    {
        var sProp = obj.css( iProp );
        propFloats[ iProp ] = 0.0; // in the beginning all floats is 0
    }


    var animInterval = setInterval( 
        function()
        {
            var curTime = _getTime();

            if( curTime <= startTime + duration )
            {
                var timeDiff = curTime - startTime;
                var step = easing( timeDiff / duration, timeDiff, 0, 1, duration );

                var dStep;

                var prevStep = asyncAnimate._prevSteps[ animNum ];

                if( prevStep == null )
                {
                    dStep = step;
                }
                else
                {
                    dStep = step - prevStep;                        
                }

                asyncAnimate._prevSteps[ animNum ] = step;

                for( var iProp in props )
                {                   
                    var prop = props[ iProp ];

                    // we can increment int px only (for crossbrowser solution),
                    // so, we need to save a float part                 

                    var propStep = prop * dStep;

                    // calculate total int part
                    var savedFloatPart = propFloats[ iProp ];

                    var totalPropStep = propStep + savedFloatPart;
                    var totalPropStepInt = parseInt( totalPropStep );
                    var totalPropStepFloat = totalPropStep - totalPropStepInt;

                    if( Math.abs( totalPropStepInt ) > 0 )
                    {                                                   
                        obj.css( iProp, "+=" + String( totalPropStepInt ) + "px" );
                    }

                    // reset saved int/float parts
                    propFloats[ iProp ] = totalPropStepFloat;
                }
            }
            else
            {                   
                clearInterval( animInterval );
            }
        },
        10 
    );

    asyncAnimate._animNum++;
}

asyncAnimate._prevSteps = {};
asyncAnimate._animNum = 0;
```

Examples of usage (do not forgent to include a [js with easing functions](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/)) or [create your own](http://forrst.com/posts/How_to_create_custom_jQuery_easing_functions-OKb):

```
asyncAnimate( $( '#div1' ), { 'margin-left': 50 }, 1000, $.easing.easeInOutElastic );
// ...
asyncAnimate( $( '.green' ), { 'width': -50, 'height': -50 }, 250, $.easing.easeInOutQuad );
```

You can see [how it works](http://jsbin.com/OzaQeHe/5) (try to press buttons in very short intervals).

I hope it's easy to adapt it for some other types of animations.

It seems that [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) of jQuery does not support the behavior currently.

Comment: You did an incredible and astonishing job. Thanks for sharing this answer. Mark it as correct! +1 from me

Answer (score 1):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OnIzETI/2/edit)**

The `.stop()` method will clear your current animation. 
You can use `+=` and `-=` to update the current element position

Just for example:

```
  <input type="button" value="50" />
  <input type="button" value="-50" />
  <input type="button" value="150" />
  <input type="button" value="-150" />


  <div id="my_div"></div>
```

```
$(':button').click(function(){
  $('#my_div').stop().animate( { left: "+="+ this.value }, 2000 );
});
```

Logically if you don't need to clear the previous animation just remove `.stop()`

Comment: I'd like a new animation to be added to a previous one. I don't want my previous animation be stopped.

Comment: In your LIVE DEMO: I removed 'stop()' call: **$(':button').click**. Then I tried to click '-50' button many times in very short intervals. Animations launched one-by-one. Excuse me, but that's not exactly. A new animation must be started just when I press the button. And a previous animation must be continued. So, speed must increase.

Comment: @sergzach if the speed must increase than you need to apply a logic the the `speed` factor value

Comment: @sergzach I really don't get you, you need a linear motion? An increase of speed? what about the distance... you need to clarify your question in order to get a proper answer

Comment: Please look to the question.

Comment: Excuse me. Do you realize that your answer is not satisfying or something is not clear still?

Comment: Sorry I was away. In any case, what you want to achieve will not go that easy without applying some high math. You might need to register the changes inside the `step` property of your animate function. You can find another answer of mine that might help you to clarify a bit how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568507/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-remaining-time-of-animation

Comment: @sergzach Also, the easing you want to modify like in the graph will not be exactly the way you pictured it. Hope you're aware of that. Otherwise - the simple way - AFAIK will be a mission almost-impossible.

Comment: Thanks for the idea to implement step().

Comment: OK, I found the solution. You can look at that. Thank you for the help!